# Two combobox with databinding and the same data source

Tags: c#, mysql, data-binding

I'm working on a software project where I want to select a dataset in a MySQL database by selecting a value using a ComboBox control in C#. I use the MySQL .Net connector and everything was working fine as long as there was one ComboBox control.
I added a TabControl on the main form and on every tab, there is a copy of that ComboBox control so that the user can select the database row on each tab of the tab control. As soon as there is a second ComboBox control bound to the same data, the first ComboBox does not change its value anymore.

More specific:
Let's assume Tab1 is selected when the app is started.
On the ComboBox, there is ID 1 selected.
If changing selection to ID 20, after 1/10 second, ID 1 is selected again.

When selecting Tab2, then selecting Tab1 again, selecting another ID is working fine. Also when selecting another ID on Tab1 is working fine.

It seems as if the ComboBox control on Tab2 must have been visible at least once in order for the ComboBox control on Tab1 is working correctly.
Quite strange, right?
Does anyone know why this strange behaviour occurs?

Best regards,
Tom

Comment: Did you bind all `ComboBox`es with `TwoWay` Binding ? It seems that there's a bug in code that work when you 'set' value. It seems that there's some operation that receive value -> do something and then -> update value. That's bad because all `ComboBox`es binded to the same value :( but it hard to tell without code :(

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure about TwoWay binding. I don't think I need to specify it as I'm working with Windows Forms instead of WPF. Regarding the code, it's difficult to provide it, as I don't know which part of the code I should provide. I think the parts where I assign the data-binding properties to the controls won't help much, right?

Comment: I remember this happened with me couple of years ago. I am not sure what exactly I did, but I think this should work.

Rather than binding the source directly to comboBox, create a object and then bind the object to ComboBox.

Please try it. it might work.

Comment: can you please give me some example for that? I'm not sure I understand you.

Comment: obj1 = datasource;
obj2 = datasource;

combobox1.datasource = obj1;
combobox1.datasource = obj2;